# Access: Refer to text box from detail section of subreport from main report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I can successfully refer to the value in a text box in the subreport *footer* using `[subreportName].[Report].[textBoxName]`. However, I would like to refer to a text box in the *detail* section. Using the above just gives the last value it contained - I would like to refer to a specific one (by field, say).

Is this possible, or is there some workaround?

---

Update: This is what I have so far. `fieldA` is the name of the text box that I want to use to pick out the correct entry (the correct entry will have "keyString" in this text box), and `fieldB` contains the value I want to actually store.

In the `OnFormat` event in the subreport detail section:

```
Dim varToStore As Double
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    If Me![fieldA] = "keyString" Then
        varToStore = Me![fieldB]
    End If
End Sub
```

In a new Module:

```
Function getVariable(Name As String)
    If Name = "varToStore" Then
        getVariable = varToStore
    Else
        getVariable = -1
    End If
End Function
```

In the Control Source of the text box in the main report:

```
=getVariable("varToStore")
```

I'm using the general function getVariable since there are a few variables from the detail section that I'm planning to store, so I thought it would be easier to just pass arguments to one function, rather than having a function for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at a textbox in the detail section of a continuous form, it is really only one object, even if there are many rows on the screen.
If you change a property, you change all rows. If you read its value, you get the value of the *current* record.

With the detail section of a report, it's similar. You can't refer to the textbox of any row except the last after it has been printed.

But you can **while** it is being printed. The `OnFormat` property of the detail section is most probably the best event to use.

Something like

```
Private Sub Detailbereich_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

    If Me!Keyfield = 4711 Then
        ' do something specific with the textbox of this specific row
    End If

End Sub
```

To create this sub, open the property sheet of the details section of the subreport.
On the Events tab, select **Event procedure** for the **On Format** event. Edit it ("..." button) and you're there.

You can assign the textbox value to a public variable to pass it to the main report. But depending on where/when in the main report you want to use it, it may be too late.

Comment: I understand your first two paragraphs, and suspected as much.
Where would I put that code? If I wanted to store the value of a specific textbook in a new variable, how would I do that and then access it from the parent report?

Comment: See edit. Where exactly do you want to use the variable?

Comment: Thank you @Andre451. I would like to use the variable in a calculation in a text box in the parent report. I think that I have to pass it using a function - I've edited my attempt into the OP.

Answer (score 1):

New answer for the Update.

I assume your code doesn't work?
That would be because `getVariable("varToStore")` is evaluated when the main report is opened, but `varToStore` is set later, when the subreport is formatted.

So you need a different approach. Don't try to fish your data from the subreport, get it with SQL when the main report is opened. Something like:

```
Report_Open()
Me.mainTextField.Value = DLookup("fieldB", "SubReportTable", "fieldA = 'keyString'")
```

`mainTextField` would be unbound then.
If "keyString" is actually constant, you could even use the DLookup as control source. But I guess it's a variable, so it's easier to construct the DLookup call in VBA.

Comment: That makes sense.
The `keyString` is actually constant in this case, so just using VBA in the control source will probably save a lot of time. Thank you for finding a simpler solution to my over-complicated question!